# Unit Testing with Rhino Mocks

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I have the following method called Execute() from the Abstract class called AutoLetterGenBatch in my ConsoleApp. I am trying to unit test this.

```
public void Execute()
{
    BatchJobSecurity.Instance.CreatePrincipal();
    DoExecute();
}
```

So I set up what I believe are all the proper references and  try to invoke the method  like below .

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    AutoLetterGenBatchJob ALGBJ = new AutoLetterGenBatchJob();
    ALGBJ.Execute();
}
```

However, when I go to do the build it gives me this compilation error *Error    34  Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'AutoLetterGenBatch.AutoLetterGenBatchJob'* .

I am somewhat new to unit testing. I realize this probably isn't much of a test but I just want to see my Execute() method get hit for the time being. I have read that a good way to get around this problem with abstract classes is to set up a mock object for the abstract class. So I try to do this with RhinoMocks.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{          
    AutoLetterGenBatchJob ALGBJ = MockRepository.GenerateStub<AutoLetterGenBatchJob>();
    ALGBJ.Execute();
}
```

It now builds with all of the proper using statements in place. However when the test runs I now get this error. *Can't find a constructor with matching arguments .* Again I am pretty new to this. If someone can help me to understand what it is I need to do it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

YOur first test doesn't make any sense, your class is abstract, by definition you can't create an instance of it. In order to test that method you need a class which derives from `AutoLetterGenBatch` and you then create an instance of this class and do what is neccessary to invoke the method on this instance.

Using a mocking framework would be one way, as would creating a test class of your own. Personally I would go with the 'roll your own' at first as this will be easier to debug.

```
public class TestAutoLetterGenBatch : AutoLetterGenBatch
{

}
```

once you have this class you'll see that you need to call the constructor that `AutoLetterGenBatch` declares. This is the same issue that rhino mocks it complaining about. Without seeing the class `AutoLetterGenBatch` we can't advise any further.

For what it is worth, Rhino mocks has seen little work recently and you would probably be better using Moq or another more active framework.

Also you need to [generate a partial mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764929/rhino-mocks-partial-mock) to do the testing you want to do, no a stub.